# Can we copy Postgres extracted files from C drive to another system into C drive ? is it possible?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a Postgres database on another system using my system's C drive files.

I have installed Postgres 10 in system-1 and I am copying folder from C drive to system-2 C drive.

It this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the files in the [data directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html), rather than the actual binaries ("exe").

Yes, this is possible if **both** of the following conditions are true:

- Postgres was stopped on the source computer before you started copying the files
- the other Postgres installation is the same major version (10.1 to 10.5 is OK, but 10.10 to 11.5 is **not** OK)

You also need to make sure the the [data directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) is put in the right place on the target system. You need to check the Postgres Windows service definition to find out where the target system expects the data directory.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but i want to copy all actual binaries from .exe file and moved to another system.

Comment: Then copy the binaries. What's the problem with that?

Comment: i had done but unable to access database, could you let me know the process to start postgres database with binaries.

Comment: Just copying the binaries does not copy the actual database - you need to copy the files from the "data directory" as well as I have described in my answer.

Comment: How to [initialize](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) and [start the database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html) is documented in the manual.